# Dist folder isn't present after i run vite build

Tags: vite

I recently had to migrate a CRA app to Vite. npm run start works well but when i want to use build and then preview, it just gives me a blank page and this in the console of the page
While scooping around in the documentation, i noticed that the build files are supposed to go to a dist folder but i don't have any, i just have build, node modules, public, src and so on, could that be that problem?

`index.5736194d.js:32 Error     at t1 (index.5736194d.js:653:382)     at Qf (index.5736194d.js:662:1245)     at parse (index.5736194d.js:671:2678)     at jSe (index.5736194d.js:62:22610)     at Cl (index.5736194d.js:62:22628)     at vn (index.5736194d.js:62:22739)     at TA (index.5736194d.js:62:31943)     at lTe (index.5736194d.js:62:42096)     at Crt (index.5736194d.js:643:18137)     at N_ (index.5736194d.js:30:19578) qx @ index.5736194d.js:32 index.5736194d.js:32 Error     at t1 (index.5736194d.js:653:382)     at Qf (index.5736194d.js:662:1245)     at parse (index.5736194d.js:671:2678)     at jSe (index.5736194d.js:62:22610)     at Cl (index.5736194d.js:62:22628)     at vn (index.5736194d.js:62:22739)     at TA (index.5736194d.js:62:31943)     at Uat (index.5736194d.js:671:3198)     at N_ (index.5736194d.js:30:19578)     at gq (index.5736194d.js:32:44475) qx @ index.5736194d.js:32 index.5736194d.js:32 Error     at t1 (index.5736194d.js:653:382)     at Qf (index.5736194d.js:662:1245)     at Gat (index.5736194d.js:671:4153)     at N_ (index.5736194d.js:30:19578)     at gq (index.5736194d.js:32:44475)     at pq (index.5736194d.js:32:40098)     at jce (index.5736194d.js:32:40024)     at Xy (index.5736194d.js:32:39875)     at o8 (index.5736194d.js:32:36205)     at cq (index.5736194d.js:32:35149) qx @ index.5736194d.js:32 index.5736194d.js:32 Error     at t1 (index.5736194d.js:653:382)     at Qf (index.5736194d.js:662:1245)     at parse (index.5736194d.js:671:2678)     at jSe (index.5736194d.js:62:22610)     at Cl (index.5736194d.js:62:22628)     at vn (index.5736194d.js:62:22739)     at dTe (index.5736194d.js:62:47368)     at pTe (index.5736194d.js:62:47929)     at N_ (index.5736194d.js:30:19578)     at gq (index.5736194d.js:32:44475) qx @ index.5736194d.js:32 index.5736194d.js:32 Uncaught Error     at t1 (index.5736194d.js:653:382)     at Qf (index.5736194d.js:662:1245)     at parse (index.5736194d.js:671:2678)     at jSe (index.5736194d.js:62:22610)     at Cl (index.5736194d.js:62:22628)     at vn (index.5736194d.js:62:22739)     at TA (index.5736194d.js:62:31943)     at lTe (index.5736194d.js:62:42096)     at Crt (index.5736194d.js:643:18137)     at N_ (index.5736194d.js:30:19578)` 
I was expecting it to run right away, as the guide i was following said. Couldn't find any solutions for it either.